# fish: sudo: !!: command not found

Tags: command-history, fish

I have fish installed in my Linux Mint DE. I really like how fish makes things easier and it looks so pretty although I haven't find a correct answer about why I can't execute:

```
sudo: !!: command not found
```

At first I tried to escape the exclamation signs with sudo !! but didn't work either. Does someone know why is this failing?

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/q/719531/4714

Comment: tldr: ↑  then  Alt + S

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I haven't found a inbuilt replacement for `!!` in Fish however you can write a function that allows you to keep using `!!`

Taken from this answer https://superuser.com/a/719538/226822

```bash
function sudo --description "Replacement for Bash 'sudo !!' command to run last command using sudo."
    if test "$argv" = !!
        echo sudo $history[1]
        eval command sudo $history[1]
    else
        command sudo $argv
    end
end
```

Comment: Nice answer, However, where do I have to write it so I can make the function permanent?

Comment: You have two options .config/fish/config.fish or if you want to keep things separate put them in individual files under .config/fish/functions/newfunction1.fish newfunction2.fish etc

Comment: @vato In this can you would save the code above to ~/.config/fish/functions/sudo.fish  The name of the file should match the function inside.

Answer (score 10):

The `!!` syntax is part of the bash history substitution feature, which fish does not implement. See [this link](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/288) for a discussion. Please feel free to weigh in there on what you think fish ought to do.

The most efficient (in terms of keypresses) replacement for `sudo !!` is up-arrow to recall the last history item, ctrl-A to move to the beginning of the line, then type sudo.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification. Although, in order to run sudo with the last command by going through the history and then ctrl+A is not exclusively from fish, that's basically how bash works.

Comment: @SaulOrtega he didn't claim it was exclusively from fish, just that that method will work in fish, while `!!` will not.

Comment: Or even better, use `Ctrl+P` to get the **p**revious command and then `Ctrl+A` to go to the beginning of the line. To go all-in, use `Ctrl/Alt + B` (**B**ackward) along with `Ctrl/Alt + F` (**F**orward) to replace the arrow keys entirely, `Ctrl+E` to replace `Home` and `Ctrl+H` along with `Ctrl+W` to replace `Backspace`. These shortcuts work in all shells and in vim's *insert mode* as well.

Comment: Most efficient way these days is Alt+s, to prefix the last (or current) command with the installed privilege escalator (`sudo`/`doas`/`please`).

Comment: @ossbuntu, `Ctrl+e` would be a replacement for `End`, not `Home`.

Answer (score 6):

@ridiculous_fish's answer is outdated. The quickest way to achieve the equivalent to `sudo !!` would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>/<kbd>up-arrow</kbd> (whichever you prefer), and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to prefix the command with `sudo`.

Comment: You don't have to recall the last command anymore, you can just do `Alt+s` immediately and it'll replace the empty command line with the last command, prefixed with sudo/doas/please.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `!!` only in the context of `sudo !!`, you can define a keybinding to `^s` (CTRL+s) which prepends sudo to your command:

```
function prepend_command
  set -l prepend $argv[1]
  if test -z "$prepend"
    echo "prepend_command needs one argument."
    return 1
  end

  set -l cmd (commandline)
  if test -z "$cmd"
    commandline -r $history[1]
  end

  set -l old_cursor (commandline -C)
  commandline -C 0
  commandline -i "$prepend "
  commandline -C (math $old_cursor + (echo $prepend | wc -c))
end
```

This allows to type in any command and prepend sudo while typing or like in your case as a substitution of `sudo !!`

See the [Ahti's comment on the github discussion](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/288#issuecomment-158704275)

Answer (score 0):

Simply press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> and boom you're done in one step! The last command is freshly inserted right after the sudo command. Thanks DT!

Comment: Is this a "thank you" to the existing alt+s answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/549161/117549 ?